# Implement 3 finger drag

Tags: window, 18.10

I installed Ubuntu 18.10 yesterday, but I find myself missing some useful multitouch touchpad gestures.

In particular, I'd like to have a three finger drag gesture to move windows around.
On Ubuntu, you have to perform such a task with two hands, one to select the window and the other to drag around.

How could I implement this 3 finger gesture?

Comment: [This](https://int3ractive.com/2018/09/make-the-best-of-MacBook-touchpad-on-Ubuntu.html) might help. I have not tried it by myself though.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a gnome extension that enables the feature you're looking for.

The download link to the extension is [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2164/three-finger-window-move/).

You can also find instructions for installing gnome extensions in [this article](https://itsfoss.com/gnome-shell-extensions/).

note: it requires wayland (and it only allows you to move windows with 3 finger drag; nothing else)

Comment: Thanks for contributing to askubuntu! Consider editing your answer and explain a little bit what extensions are, where the link leads and how to download the relevant zip files (what parameters should be entered in shell version & extension version) and how to install it. This would really help unexperienced users to understand your solution.